# Organizing data into a different format in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some data that I downloaded and I need to organize it differently because there are hundreds of items already and there will probably be thousands before it's done. The simplified format when I copy/paste into excel is as follows: (Each new line is a new cell, including the space. Everything is in one column.)

```
Permit #:
1
Permit Type:
Solar
Status:
Completed

Permit #:
5
Permit Type:
Roof
Status:
Expired
```

What I need is to reorganize that into rows and columns with the Permit #, Permit Type, and Status at the top and the corresponding value below. Then I'll be able to look for duplicate and further organize it as needed. So an example with the above sample would look like this:

```
Permit #:   Permit Type:   Status: 
1           Solar          Completed
5           Roof           Expired
```

So, I need a way assign specific cells to be referenced in that way and the reference has to skip a number of rows each time.

The best I've gotten is using OFFSET but when you drag that function down, the reference cell only goes from A2 to A3 etc. Where I need the reference cell to also move down the list by the same as the offset. In my actual data I need it to OFFSET +16 rows. So I need the reference argument in OFFSET to be dynamic in that way.

What would work is if I write the function =OFFSET(A2, 16,0) and drag it down, the reference argument would change to =OFFSET(A18, 16, 0).

Is that possible? Or if someone has a better way to accomplish the same thing, I'm all ears.

Comment: I understand the desire to split one cell into 3 cells, but where does OFFSET come into play here? Why do you care about rows? That's not obvious with how you wrote your question. This may have to do with improper formatting of your sample data. See [How to format tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: What about the text to columns tool? then you could re-join what you need or drop what you don't...

Comment: I can't control the formatting of the sample data. The data is the result of a public U.S. government website search. The OFFSET idea was just the best idea I've had so far since the data comes out in a long string under one column and in a repeating pattern.

Comment: As far as text to column, I tried that too but couldn't get a delimiter to work consistently. That was also after trying to add delimiters with find and replace. For instance, finding all of the "permit #:" and replacing with "@permit #:" and then using the "@" as a delimiter in text to column.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick approach, based on the pattern shown in the input data.

```
=LET(in, TOROW(A:A,1), nf, 3, seq, SEQUENCE(nf,,1,2),w, WRAPROWS(in,2*nf),
 data, CHOOSECOLS(w,seq+1),header,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(w,seq)),VSTACK(header, data))
```

[image: output]

It assumes there is no need to clean the data, all field names are the same, etc. The name `nf`, represents the number of fields per record. It considers the field values in the even columns and the field names in the odd ones. `TOCOL` with the second input argument removes the empty rows that act as a record delimiter.